# Proving $\rm{card}(\Bbb Z)=\rm{card}(\Bbb N)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm trying to prove that the set of integers has the same cardinality as the set of naturals just using the definition, that is, I'm trying to find a bijective function between the two sets. I found this [Why do the rationals, integers and naturals all have the same cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182236/why-do-the-rationals-integers-and-naturals-all-have-the-same-cardinality) but I couldn't quite find the answer. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT(ish):

Let $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$ be the bijection in question, $f(0)=0$, and for any natural number $n$, let $f(n)=2n$. Can you complete the construction for what the negative integers are mapped to?

Comment: The odd numbers? 2|x|-1

Comment: Indeed. Note that you can simplify it a little bit since, when $n$ is negative, $|n|=-n$, so $2|n|-1 = -2n-1$.