# What will be $ | \mathbb Q^2|$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$ | \mathbb Q^2|$ I assume that it has to be continuum, but I have no idea, how to show it

Comment: If $X$ is infinite, then $|X| = |X^2|$.

Comment: Do you know the mapping from $\mathbb{N}^2\mapsto \mathbb{N}$ that lets you show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable? Can you see how you might be able to use that mapping to show that $\mathbb{Q}^2\equiv(\mathbb{N}^2)^2\mapsto\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be $\aleph_0$.

$|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Q}|\\
|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}^2|\\
|\mathbb{N}^2|=|\mathbb{Q}^2|\\$

Answer (score 3):

Do you know that $|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{Q}|$? If not, the argument can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182236/why-do-the-rationals-integers-and-naturals-all-have-the-same-cardinality). The same argument tells you that $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}^2|$, just replace the sequences of integers with sequences of rational numbers. In terms of cardinals, we have

$$\aleph_0^4=(\aleph_0^2)^2=\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0$$