# Prove that the set of all open intervals with rational endpoints are countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove that the set of all open intervals with rational endpoints are countable, I do not know exactly what shall I do, Could anyone help me please?

Comment: This cardinality will be less than or equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ and greater than or equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$.  So it suffices to show that $| \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}| = | \mathbb{Q}|$.

Comment: All comments and answers from this other recent question [What will be $ | \mathbb Q^2|$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207355/what-will-be-mathbb-q2) apply.

Comment: Then interval (a,b) is uniquely determined by the ordered pair <a,b> where a < b.  the set of all <a,b> were b>a and a,b are rational is a subset of Q x Q.  which is countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Furthermore, you should know that a finite product of countable sets is countable, so $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. (If you don't know this, prove it!) You can construct a bijection from your set to $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ the natural way, so that set will also be countable.

Comment: you that the bijection is constructed in the natural way?

Comment: By natural, I just mean the easiest way to do it? In this case, as fleablood described in the comments, you map an open interval $(a,b)$ with rational endpoints to the ordered pair $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. You can show fairly easily that this is an injection, so $|\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}|\geq |I|$ where $I$ is the set of open intervals with rational endpoints. (This isn't a bijection, since if $a>b, (a,b)$ is not an interval (or, at best, it's a degenerate interval).